# UITableViewController change the color of multiple selection circle

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a black background and would like the user to be able to select multiple rows at once. **The default style of this selection is a small gray circle to the left of the row.**  Unfortunately **it is not visible on a black background**. How can I supply a custom image for that or set it's appearance to be something else?

```
//this enables a little gray circle  to select multiple rows
 self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;

//my table has black background and the circle is not visible
 self.tableView.backgroundColor = [AppColors tableViewBackgroundColor];
 self.tableView.separatorColor = [AppColors tableViewBackgroundColor];
```

Answer (score 2):

`UITableViewCell` has two properties called `backgroundView` and `multipleSelectionBackgroundView`. Just create a view with the proper background color and use a `UIImageView` to display your own custom image for unselected and selected states.

Comment: The multipleSelectionBackgroundView changes the background for the selected view, leaving the checkmark intact. This makes me believe that the checkmark is some other view associated with the cell